# Can I say "occasion" instead of "time"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Can I say **occasion** instead of **time**? For example:

> I remember the **occasion** when my kitten broke the vase. I was upset
>   because that vase cost me a lot!

Or should I only say:

> I remember the **time** when my kitten broke the vase. I was upset
>   because that vase cost me a lot!

Comment: To my ear, **the occasion when**, although it is grammatical, sounds a little old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are acceptable, because 'occasion' and 'time' are synonymous in this context.